# Count word length with occurrence javascript

Tags: javascript, word-count, word-frequency

Write a function that takes a string consisting of one or more space separated words, and returns an object that shows the number of words of different sizes. Words consist of any sequence of non-space characters.

This is what I have so far

```
  const strFrequency = function (stringArr) {
    return stringArr.reduce((count,num) => {
  count [num] = (count[num] || 0) + 1;
    return count;
  },
  {})
  }

  let names = ["Hello world it's a nice day"];

  console.log(strFrequency(names)); // { 'Hello world it\'s a nice day': 1 } I need help splitting the strings
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: *Write a function that takes a string*... So why did you write one that takes an array?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Change your function to take a string and call `.split(/\s+/)` on it. Then go about your counting, but use `word.length` rather than `num` which is just an index. It's important to learn [how to run and debug small programs like this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Seems you copied code from somewhere that does a different job. What have *you* done so far? Share the reasoning on how you ended up with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process: Check if it is an invalid input then return blank object else process it by splitting it into words then adding into an array of the same length in state object.
Hope this is what you were looking for!

```
const str = "Hello world it's a nice day";

function getOccurenceBasedOnLength(str = ''){
  if(!str){
    return {};
  }
  return str.split(' ').reduce((acc,v)=>{
    acc[v.length] = acc[v.length] ? [...acc[v.length], v] : [v];
    return acc;
  },{});
}


console.log(getOccurenceBasedOnLength(str));
```

Output

```
{
  '1': [ 'a' ],
  '3': [ 'day' ],
  '4': [ "it's", 'nice' ],
  '5': [ 'Hello', 'world' ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//str='The dog jumped over the shipyard fence'


function wordLengths(str){

    const newArrayList=str.split(" ");

    let newStr="";

      for(let i=0;i<newArrayList.length;i++){
        newStr+=newArrayList[i]
      }
     return newStr.length;
}
```